# WPF Binding Label Content to Property

Tags: c#, wpf

I have read several articles about this and can't quite seem to get my label to update when my property is changed. The PropertyChanged event is firing, and the property is updating to the new text but the label is not updating. 
Thanks for the help!

XAML

```
 <Grid.Resources>
     <c:UserInformation x:Key="myTaskData"/>
 </Grid.Resources>
 <Label Name="lblTaskNameTitle" Content="{Binding Path=propTaskName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Window

```
 UserInformation t = new UserInformation();                

 t.propTaskName = "Updated Task Name";
 this.DataContext = t.propTaskName;
```

Code Behind

```
class UserInformation : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
        private string strTaskName = "Task Name: ";
        public string propTaskName
        {
            get { return this.strTaskName; }
            set 
            { 
                this.strTaskName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("propTaskName");  //Call the method to set off the PropertyChanged event.
            }
        }

        //INotifyPropertyChanged stuff  
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));  
            }
        }
```

Updated to reflect comment suggestions.

Comment: Where are you setting `myTaskData`? It seems like that should be your `DataContext` instead of the task name.

Comment: myTaskData is set in the Grid.Resources section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xaml should be:

```
<Label Name="lblTaskNameTitle" Content="{Binding Path=propTaskName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

UserInformation t = new UserInformation();               
t.propTaskName = "Updated Task Name";
this.DataContext = t;
```

Comment: I have updated the xaml to reflect this and the label is still not updating? Other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Bindings look at the DataContext, not the code behind. You can make them the same thing by adding DataContext = this to your code behind, although you would want to use a separate class.